# cyclic relationships between nodes in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

i'm working with neo4j and python (with py2neo), i need to put something like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAzLq.png , in the database. Currently i have this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6skO.png, with this cypher query

```
grafoNeo4j.cypher.execute("merge (n1:k_mer {name : '"+src.k_1_mer+"'}) 
merge (n2:k_mer {name : '"+dst.k_1_mer+"'}) merge (n1)-[:solapa]-(n2)")
```

where:

- grafoNeo4j , is my graph in the db.
- src.k_1_mer and dst.k_1_mer , are the nodes name

my idea is to get the graph of the first image, wit the corresponding cyclic relationships in the database.
Hope that this is clear enough.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is no reason to have identical relationships between the same 2 nodes. Are your relationships supposed to have distinguishing properties?

Comment: Or, perhaps you just need your relationships to contain a `count` property?

Comment: Maybe the count property is a nice way to solve this, gonna try. The reason behind this is to test a real example of DNA assembly so the identical relationships are bound to happen in repeated sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a waste of resources to have identical copies of the same relationship between 2 nodes. You can instead maintain a count property on a single relationship. The optional `ON CREATE` and `ON MATCH` subclauses for the `MERGE` clause make this very easy.

For example:

```
MERGE (n1:k_mer {name : 'a'}) 
MERGE (n2:k_mer {name : 'b'})
MERGE (n1)-[r:solapa]-(n2)
ON CREATE SET r.cnt = 1
ON MATCH SET r.cnt = r.cnt + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, solved my issue beautifully, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is simple one.

This is query for the picture above:

```
CREATE (long_:Node {name: "long_"})
CREATE (ong_t:Node {name: "ong_t"})
CREATE (ng_ti:Node {name: "ng_ti"})
CREATE (g_tim:Node {name: "g_tim"})
CREATE (_time:Node {name: "_time"})
CREATE (ong_l:Node {name: "ong_l"})
CREATE (ng_lo:Node {name: "ng_lo"})
CREATE (g_lon:Node {name: "g_lon"})
CREATE (_long:Node {name: "_long"})
CREATE (a_lon:Node {name: "a_lon"})

CREATE (_long)-[:solapa]->(long_)
CREATE (_long)-[:solapa]->(long_)
CREATE (_long)-[:solapa]->(long_)
CREATE (a_lon)-[:solapa]->(_long)
CREATE (long_)-[:solapa]->(ong_l)
CREATE (long_)-[:solapa]->(ong_l)
CREATE (long_)-[:solapa]->(ong_t)
CREATE (ong_t)-[:solapa]->(ng_ti)
CREATE (ng_ti)-[:solapa]->(g_tim)
CREATE (g_tim)-[:solapa]->(_time)
CREATE (ong_l)-[:solapa]->(ng_lo)
CREATE (ong_l)-[:solapa]->(ng_lo)
CREATE (ng_lo)-[:solapa]->(g_lon)
CREATE (ng_lo)-[:solapa]->(g_lon)
CREATE (g_lon)-[:solapa]->(_long)
CREATE (g_lon)-[:solapa]->(_long)
```

You can just copy-paste it to Neo4j browser to verify.

Result:

[image: result]

**Note:** be careful with `MERGE` statements, do not overuse them when they are not needed.

Comment: I'm gonna try this in my code and let you know. Thanks